# Extracting value from list created with conditional string in list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension, walrus-operator

What I have:

```
series = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo' ]
column = [1, 2, -3, -4, 5, -6]


list = [column[function(x)].count() for x in series]

list:
foo = 3
bar = 1
baz = 2
```

Works fine, each instance in series is counted.

Want only positive number instances counted as well, so:

```
list = [column[function(x)].count() for x in series if (x := function(x)) >= 0]

list:

foo = 1
bar = 1
baz = 1
```

Discovered Walrus Operator, but x in my case is a string, perhaps the core problem?

I do get a syntax error with Walrus portion of code.

I need both total & positive number counts, creating say a "total" & "positive totals" columns in function seems clunky, is there a way to do this with list comprehension.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What python version are you using?  You need at least 3.8

Comment: 3.7.9 That's it!  Will upgrade and report back.  Thank you.  Gribble's suggestion vals = [column[y].count() for x in series if (y := function(x)) >= 0]  seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `pandas`:

```
pd.Series(column).gt(0).groupby(series).agg({'count','sum'})
```

Output:

```
     count  sum
bar      1    1
baz      2    1
foo      3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `function(x)` where `x` is the result of `function(x)` already.  Try:

```
vals = [column[y].count() for x in series if (y := function(x)) >= 0]
```

Notes:

1. Use a different variable name than `x` so that it is less confusing (this is probably also the source of your syntax error).
2. `list` is a type name, choose a different name for the list of values.